# Copy dynamic canvas into another canvas not working

Tags: javascript, canvas

I`m dealing with a video communication based on canvas.

Today, I meet a weird bug when I try to capture the video into another canvas. It sometimes worked, but sometimes not.

Here`s the code.

```js
$('#snap-button').on('click', function () {
  var source = $('#video')[0];
  var target = $('#photo')[0];
  var context = target.getContext('2d');
  context.drawImage(source, 0, 0, 800, 600);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- video -->
<canvas id="video" width="800" height="600"></canvas>

<!-- snapshot -->
<canvas id="photo" width="800" height="600"></canvas>

<button id="snap-button"></button>
```

```

But when I test this bug, I replace the video canvas with static canvas, such as draw a retangle, it worked 100% correctly, but dynamic is almost not worked.

What should I do ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Edit this code below how you want. This is working example how you can make snapshot from video into canvas.

```js
var v = document.getElementById("video1");
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
$("#snap-button").click(function(){
    ctx.drawImage(v,5,5,260,125)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Video to use:</p>

<video id="video1" controls width="270" autoplay>
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.ogg" type='video/ogg'>
  <source src=http://www.w3schools.com/tags/"mov_bbb.webm" type='video/webm'>
</video>

<p>Snapshot:</p>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="270" height="135" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
  
<br><br>
<input type="button" id="snap-button" value="Snap shot">
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_drawimage_video

Comment: Code only answers are bad, mkay?

Comment: Sorry the code just to show the scene, it cannot run.

Comment: the video tag is running well that I tested, but the Video Steam is not OK, the code I have seen in WebRTC Demo